# IE9 devicePixelRatio equivalent

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, media-queries, porting, dpi

Has anyone discovered a reliable method to determine the device pixel ratio for Windows Phone 7.5 (Mango).

It is based off of IE9. In Webkit based browsers we have window.devicePixelRatio or using window.matchMedia() with the appropriate media query.

In Windows Mobile I can determine pixel ratio by doing:
screen.deviceXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI
though this appears to only be reliable once the page has been fully rendered. Prior to that deviceXDPI reports the same as logicalXDPI

Has anyone found a solution?

Thanks for any help/suggestions

Comment: Like http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/iewebdevelopment/thread/36398b71-86c5-433b-a3b5-9f54d75f466a ?

Comment: yes, similar to that person's issue. The window.devicePixelRatio property is simply not supported on Windows Phone, though the device has a device-pixel-ratio of 1.5. It is important for me to load higher res versions of assets for those devices with higher pixel ratios. This must happen client-side as well.

Comment: Is there really a noticable difference with your images on multiple WP devices? Can ou provide an exmaple image and the devices you're seeing the differences on?

Answer (score 0):

Use [(min/max-)resolution](http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/06/14/unprefix-webkit-device-pixel-ratio/) as the equivalent test in a media query:

```
@media (min-resolution: 1.5dppx), (min-resolution: 144dpi), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2) {}
```

or through matchMedia:

```
if (window.matchMedia) 
  {
  if (window.matchMedia('(resolution: 96dpi)').matches) { }
  // resolution feature & dppx unit
  if (window.matchMedia('(min-resolution: 1dppx)').matches) { }
  // -webkit-device-pixel-ratio feature
  if (window.matchMedia('(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)').matches) { }
  // -o-device-pixel-ratio feature
  if (window.matchMedia('(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1/1)').matches) { }
  }
```

**References**

- [MSDN - resolution media feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh453730.aspx)
- [CSS WG Blog – How to unprefix -webkit-device-pixel-ratio](http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/06/14/unprefix-webkit-device-pixel-ratio/)